# snapshot doesnt show until i close the app on the simulator xcode firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Problem: Im trying to grap data from firebase realtime db and use it in my ios app, I am trying to access the value with a snapshot, but when I run the simulator, and I try adding a value in firebase it doesnt appear in the xcode cmd as a snapshot until a quit the app and it shows this error

> [80385:1296311] [Common] Snapshot request 0x600003590030 complete with error: <NSError: 0x60000359a430; domain: FBSSceneSnapshotErrorDomain; code: 4; reason: "an unrelated condition or state was not satisfied">

[image]

and in the simulator the app doesnt show its just a white screen

contentview:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseDatabase
import UserNotifications

class read: ObservableObject{
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    @Published var values: [Int]=[]
    func readVal(){
        let db = ref.child("ar")
        db.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            self.values.append (snapshot.value as! Int)
        })
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var readData = read()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Rectangle()
                .trim(from:0.1735,to:1)
                .stroke(Color.black,lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 170.0, height: 320.0)
                ZStack {
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 166.0, height: (CGFloat(readData.values.first ?? 1)*31.5))
                    
                }.padding(.top,-((CGFloat(readData.values.first ?? 1 )*31.5)+10))
                
            Text(String(readData.values.first ?? 1))
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

in appdelegate, I tried what is commented out and the other:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
@main
//struct Cl_FlowApp: App {
//    init() {
//            FirebaseApp.configure()
//        }
//        var body: some Scene {
//            WindowGroup {
//                ContentView()
//            }
//        }
//    }
//
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application:UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?)-> Bool{
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
    }
//    init() {
//                FirebaseApp.configure()
//            }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried so many ways to solve it but its not working the snapshot is empty even thought its connected to firebase realtime db.`your text`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to not match your data structure. You're reading the value of `ar` and then asking for the value of the snapshot as an `Int`. But the `ar` node in the screenshot has multiple child nodes/properties, so that'd map to a `Dictionary` in your code.

If you just want to read one specific int value, use this instead:

```
let db = ref.child("ar/a") // 
db.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    self.values.append (snapshot.value as! Int)
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer actually I wanted to read all the nodes and append their values to the list values, I did try to read one values whit your suggestion now I was debugging in xcode cause I wasn't able to see the value still, and it gives me this error ```error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.```

Comment: First off: does it make sense why your code throws the error it does after reading the first half of my answer, where I explain that? --- Second: did you search for the error message you now get already? I see some promising explanations for the new problem when I do that.